# Data transfer between module - Verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga

In Verilog I have the main module, which should accept data through an input number and set them on the wire BCD16.
In the submodule I have an output number, whose number sets (i.e. 'h358), but the value doesn't come to the wire BCD16.
The compiler doesn't show any errors.
The code is as following:

```
module LED_7seg(
    input clk, number,
....
);

....
wire [15 : 0] set; 
assign set = number;
  ....
endmodule
```

Submodul

```
module setNumber(
    output number
);

wire [15 :0] set;
assign set = 'h358;

assign number = set;

endmodule
```

Modules are connected:

[image: Connection between module]

Comment: Are you trying to send `number` from `setNumber` to `LED_7seg` serially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `LED_7seg` you have to connect your wire `set` to output of `setNumber` module and you will have your number value inside main module.

In `LED_7seg` there should not be number input. It is not needed there. Just use the wire that will come from `setNumber` module.

Remember about width of wires / regs.

Should look like that:

```
module LED_7seg(
    input clk
);

wire [15 : 0] set; 

    setNumber setNumberInstance(
        .number(set)
    );

endmodule
```

Comment: Thank for reply. I have another questions, I would like use global reg, now I have this: 'Temp = SPI_slave.byte_data_received;' but compiler return Error: 'code'(External reference SPI_slave.byte_data_received remains unresolved)

Comment: Ask question and paste the code. It is hard to say somethidng without code. Don't forget to mark if my answer was helpful or / and it was the solution. Other people would need this marks.